# Execute a file in global scope instead of returning exported object

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

In NodeJS I would like to simply execute a file and allow it to make modifications to the global namespace. I know that this is not the best practice, and if I was designing the project myself, I would make sure that each module exports a single variable.

I am converting a poorly structured SPA project joined by script tags into node, and I would like to do so incrementally.

Right now I have:

`require('./three.js')`

This is a version of threejs which simply fills a global variable named 'THREE' with the contents of the module. Since the execution of require implicitly creates a closure, a global variable is not created for me.

So what I'd like to do is just run an entire js file and allow it to create global variables.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: *"Since the execution of require implicitly creates a closure, a global variable is not created for me."* That really depends on how `three.js` is implemented. Any module can add something to the global scope by doing `global.foobar = 42`. If `three.js` is exporting a value like you'd expect, you can add it to the global object with `global.THREE = require('...')`.

Comment: Good point-- this version of three.js is expecting to just be concatenated into a webpage by a script tag, so it doesn't have this. It would be trivially added if I had a single module, but this depends on 30+ script tags, and I don't want to change them until I can incrementally test when I break it. First thing I'm doing is getting everything into a single js file instead of relying on html-embedded scripts. I will be going through and replacing each module I can with AMD-friendly versions, but this is an intermediary step.

Comment: You don't run node.js code IN the global namespace.  Any node module can directly access the `global` object to mess with the global namespace if it wants.  Why not just do it that way?  Or, even better learn how to properly program with node modules and exports since that's generally a better way to code in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question. I know how to write AMD, and I'm aware of how this is usually done. I'm asking about a special case for the sake of incremental integration of legacy code. As I mentioned, I don't want to modify the module source as there are 30+ modules included. Otherwise, what you've mentioned would be a reasonable solution.

Comment: Well, node.js does not run your code directly in the global namespace ever.  Your first line of code in a node.js program is encapsulated inside a function scope and `require()` does the same.  If you want to pretend that everything is in the same scope, then you can concatenate all the files together and load them all at once or you can write your own loader that uses `eval()` and load them all into the exact same scope.  They won't be in the global scope, but if all your code is in the same scope, that should not matter.

Comment: Feel free to examine the [implementation of `require()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L285) if you want to use that as a starting point for your own module loader that loads code into an existing scope rather than into a new scope.

Comment: See [`vm.runInThisContext()`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) for info on how `require()` runs code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this snippet. It isn't native in Node, but it works well as a provisional solution!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var includeInThisContext = function(path) {
    var code = fs.readFileSync(path);
    vm.runInThisContext(code, path);
}.bind(this);
includeInThisContext("<PATH_TO_FILE>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working on Single Page Application which use the node server to run. So why don't you try module.exports =  so that you can see that under the name space you give.

So example 
var THREE_74 = require('./three');

Now this THREE_74.HemispherLight()

you can access probably this what you doing.

And if you want to bring your application out of node than use same layout as present ( since you are converting the SPA application) and then create your index.html load the require.js file ( http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html ) into the script tag make all your file than call after this js file ( into those file do the require as you are doing now ).

then run single line server python -m SimpleHTTPServer and run on the browser simple :)

Comment: As I mentioned above, these modules are expecting to be concatenated in a script tag and many do not have export statements. I understand the conventional use of require, I am asking about a special case.